# Is there a per-method cost to object instantiation in Java?

Tags: java

I am hearing from another developer that an object is too expensive to instantiate repeatedly because "it has a bunch of methods."

My understanding (from Bloch, mostly) was that object creation is costly mostly through things done explicitly in the constructor, especially creating other expensive objects.

Is there a per-method cost for a new object in Java?  I'm thinking not, but I need references if anyone has them.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest making a class which has no methods and another one which has 100 methods, then timing how long it takes to instantiate each one a million times or so. Then do it several more times to make sure. (My knee-jerk response would be that no, methods don't make a difference. But don't take my word for it.)

Comment: I need to create some timing testers for this kind of thing.  Are there any already out there?  Another SO question....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Many methods means a big [virtual method table (VMT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table). However, the VMT is per class just like metadata and therefore does only have at most a one-time cost on the very first instantiation. Subsequent instantiations are just as fast as objects with less methods, assuming that the constructor(s) do not do heavy lifting.

Worth a read is also the chapter on [object creation from the performance tuning book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/javapt/chapter/ch04.html).

Comment: *"... only have at most a one-time cost on the very first instantiation"*.  Actually, the cost is incurred at class loading time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The book looks a bit out of date, but I'm taking a look.

Comment: @Stephen C, that might depend on the VM used and how the JIT works. That's why I wrote "at most" - it may lazily load the classes, and the class may be loaded quite late, basically triggered by their instantiation.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no relationship between the number of methods on a class and the time for the JVM to perform a `new` operation.

Seriously, if you are thinking at this sort of level you shouldn't be using a language like Java, go and write your application in assembler or 'C'.

The truth is you should concentrate on the design of your algorithms and data structures, these will have a much more profound effect on your applications performance than any potential micro optimisation.

Comment: +1 for highlighting that if you think object creation performance is an issue you shouldn't be using java...

Comment: If you read my question carefully, you'll see that I'm not the one "thinking at this level" - I'm trying to create a good design, but am running into resistance based upon unfounded claims.  Insult not appreciated.

Comment: @inflagranti FYI there's a whole chapter on it in the book referenced earlier, and also in Effective Java.  I'll let you go tell the authors they shouldn't be using Java ;)

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, there would be a slight performance hit for a class with many instance variables (not sure it would really be measurable though).  Java requires each instance variable to be set to 0, false, null for each new instance and there is a runtime cost associated with setting them to zero.  However it is probably just a memset (or calloc or something like that) which is fast to complete.